# What is the correct name for the places where net filaments cross?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-usage

E.g., fishing/cargo nets are made of monofilaments that cross and constitute the net: what are the names of those intersections? I'm wondering whether 'nodes' or 'links' could work.

I'm trying to say that a certain phenomenon is dispersed throughout a net-like structure, where no single _____ is responsible for the occurrence, but rather, all of them together (the same way no single 'node' of a net catches fish, but all of them together).

Comment: Aren't those just knots? (For the fishing nets, that is.) http://netting.nightshaderose.com/the-basic-netting-knot It doesn't seem to work for your analogy though. Perhaps consider a spider web?

Comment: Continued: “each little piece of that funny behavior has a fundamental role to play" http://news.mit.edu/2012/spider-web-strength-0202

Comment: 'Lattice points' applies with a grid, but probably doesn't get used by many fishermen.

Comment: @Stan But I mentioned the compound noun (used in maths), not the simplex one.

Comment: Let me simplify. The compound noun 'lattice points' applies with a grid, but probably doesn't get used by many fishermen.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Yes. Given, but I didn't acknowledge your comment in number. I didn't see a specific need to address in a comment what appeared to me to be moot. I used a singular "Points ***is*** the term…" but it was lost. Mea culpa.

Comment: They're *knots* in a fishing net, *nodes* in a computer network.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are knots in fact used in making or repairing nets and are simple and robust at dispersing the net yield.

The actual terminology used for the trawl (netting) refers to the mesh (opening) size and the twine (line) gauge. The trawl is composed of bars (rows of openings) and points (the knots). The size of the trawl is then given in bars. Insofar as referring to one specifically, your "node" would describe a "point" intersection of the twine made between bars.

Comment: Thank you, I was looking for this—maybe include this link (from the comments) to help ground the idea: http://netting.nightshaderose.com/the-basic-netting-knot

Answer (score -1):

Samuel Johnson's [definition](http://www.samueljohnson.com/definitions.html) of a network comes to mind:

> Any thing reticulated or decussated, at equal distances, with
>   interstices between the intersections. (See how he defined
>   'reticulated,' below.)

And:

> Reticulated: Made of network; formed with interstitial vacuities.

Perhaps one of those is the word you're looking for?